# Fantastic Four: Franklin controls Galactus

Tags: story-identification, marvel, episode-identification, fantastic-four, galactus

I'd like to know: what's the comic in which this happened?

[image]

Comment: *sings* Oh, my, my, my Galactus...

Answer (score 6):

It's from [*Fantastic Four*: Issue #604](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Fantastic_Four_Vol_1_604), published May, 2012.

Comment: Is there any "extra details" that I need to know for reading it?

Comment: @TMoraes: There's a decent summary of it at https://fanfix.wordpress.com/2012/11/25/bad-galactus-stories/ along with a rant about why the author feels it was a bad idea. :)

Comment: @TMoraes It would be best if you've read the comics to lead up to it, but if you have a basic understanding of the F4, Galactus and Franklin Richards, you should be good.